# Is it ok to ask a question to help you complete an answer you are writing?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

Suppose you are answering a question, and your answer describes a solution but it is not quite complete.  Is it ok to ask a new question to help finish your answer?  In this case, the question you are asking is completely separate from the one you are answering.  In effect, you solved one aspect of the original question, but you need a separate fix to get your solution to work properly.

The Q&A that prompted this meta question:

- [Answer to original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534029/4320665)
- [Question to complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534163/two-way-binding-doent-work-when-using-variable-twice)

Comment: If the questions are not duplicates, in that the answer to their question would not then also answer the question they were answering, neither question is a duplicate of any other question on the site, and both questions are on-topic and not too broad or primarily opinion based, then I see no problem with it myself.

Comment: That's kinda how I was leaning, and I think in this case they aren't duplicates or otherwise off-topic.  They are completely different approaches to the same problem, each with distinct problems.  It was just a bit surprising to see the same models appear twice.

Comment: They look fine to me. Two separate, though, related questions. It's better than dragging out an answer in comments trying to get complete code. And certainly better than someone asking additional questions through edits to their OP.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the input.  So it pretty much boils down to determining if each question can stand on its own?  Is it similar to the OP asking a follow-up question to a different specific aspect of the same large problem?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I would look at it.

Comment: I think i should have forked plunker from one problem to another.